# ¿Enviar array en una variable formData en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, formdata

como puedo enviar en un variable un arreglo con un formData desde javascript

Intente con el siguiente codigo, pero el php no recibe nada en el array

```
$(".dropdown-menu a.btn_1").on('click', function() {    
     var fila = $(this).parents("tr");
     var valores = "";
     var cantidad = fila.find(".cantidadProducto").val();
     var nombre =fila.find(".nombre_producto").text();
     var costo =fila.find(".costo_producto").text();
     var idp =fila.find(".id_producto").text();
     var aExtras   = [];
     $(this).parent().find('.ul_extras li').each(function() {
        var check = $(this).find('input').prop('checked');
        if (check){
             var eitems =  new Array();
             eitems["nombre"]=$(this).find('input').parent().find('span').text();
             eitems["costo"]=$(this).find('input').val();            
          aExtras.push(eitems);
        }
      });
        console.log(aExtras)            
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('nombre',nombre);
        formData.append('cantidad',cantidad);
        formData.append('costo',costo);
        formData.append('id',idp);
        formData.append('op','1');                      
        formData.append('data', JSON.stringify( aExtras));
       $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().dropdown("toggle");
        $.ajax({
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          url: 'gestar_pedido.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          success: function(v) {
                 $('#carListDetail tbody').html(v);
                 TotalCarrito()
                $('#message').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $('#message').delay(1000).fadeOut();
                });
            } //success
        }) // ajax  
});
```

En php para verificar que recibe implemento el siguiente código

```
$DATA = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($DATA);
```

Espero sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, el problema estaba en la declaración de una variable.

```
var eitems =  new Array();
```

Cuando la declaro asi

```
var eitems =  {}
```

Todo funcionó.

Espero le sirva alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

No se en este momento que es un formdata. Para enviar los datos de la forma que planteas te sirve un objeto, por ejemplo:

```
const data = {
    'nombre': 'Foo',
    'cantidad': 1, 
    ...   
    'data': JSON.stringify(aExtras)
};
```

o

```
const data = {};
data.nombre = 'Foo';
data.cantidad = 1;
...
data.data = JSON.stringify(aExtras);
```

Comment: Voy a probar el código

Comment: Como trabajo con la información en el php? intente leerlo con $_REQUEST['data'] pero no sale nada.

Comment: @AlldesignWeb, siempre puedes ver lo que llega al servidor con un `var_dump('$_REQUEST)` para el caso creo que es correcto recoger los datos con `$_REQUEST['data']`. El problema: con *peticiones ajax* no podemos hacer un `var_dump` para ver los datos que llegan, porque interrumpimos la petición, y solo vemos un error 500 o similar. Puedes completar la llamada, es decir devolver una respuesta como si todo estuviera correcto, y volcar datos en un fichero de log o algo parecido para ver que llego al servidor. Empieza por enviar solo un string, p.e. el nombre en el objeto data y ve a más..

Comment: El problema es que envió al modulo una opción para saber que acción se debe hacer.  No logro obtener los valores.

Answer (score 0):

hoy día, para el 2023, estoy haciéndolo de la siguiente manera:

```
var form = new FormData();
// form.append("fields[0]", JSON.stringify(fields));<-- antes
// debajo como lo hago actualmente.
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][id]", fields.id);
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][name]", fields.name);
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][description]", fields.description);
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][type]", fields.type);
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][active]", fields.active);
form.append("fields["+fields.id+"][created_at]", fields.created_at);
```

Acá estoy pasando un array asociativo, con el id del objeto fields como clave, luego a esa clave le asigno varias propiedades asociativas en su respectiva clave => valor, lo que en el backend php se leeria de la siguiente manera:

```
fields => array:1 [
  10 => array:6 [
    "id" => "10"
    "name" => "Gestion de Compras a Terceros"
    "description" => "Gestion de Compras a Terceros"
    "type" => "0"
    "active" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2023-10-24"
  ]
]
```

En donde podemos observar que el objeto fields es un array que ocupa una sola posición la cual su clave es el numero 10 y su valor es otro array de 6 posiciones con cada uno de sus atributos asignados en clave => valor.

De esta forma se puede procesar la información mas rápido tal cual si fuera un formulario que se esta enviando.!